# deploying a war file in cloud9-ide

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am trying to create a GWT application in cloud9. Their are no default runners for GWT but I figured I could build the war file and deploy it within the cloud9 environment. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your own runner or just run the application from the Terminal. Check the [documentation](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/run-an-application).